# Russian text displaying as ??? in my Angular app

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I have an app which is reading information from an SQL database and displaying in a table. 
The information in the SQL table is in Russian and has collation utf8_unicode_ci. I am using Angular.

Everything works fine - data is being displayed, however the text is displaying as ????? rather than the Russian text.

How do I fix this error? I have tried googling but cant find anything relevant.

Here is the head element of my index.html:

```
<html ng-app="crudApp">
<head>
<title>Burger King Stock List</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Include Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Include main CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<!-- Include jQuery library -->
<script src="js/jQuery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include AngularJS library -->
<script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include Bootstrap Javascript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

I am thinking i needed to have another meta tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to support UTF-8 completely in a web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/how-to-support-utf-8-completely-in-a-web-application)

Comment: It does have good information - thanks. I am a learner so its not entirely clear to me. What i am trying to understand is where do i specify utf8, is it after i make connection to the db or is it where i query the db? @CharlotteDunois